# ¿Cómo devolver un valor de cantidad total de booleanos?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Tengo una función que recibe como argumento un objeto 'usuario', cada `property` de ese objeto es un objeto cada usuario tiene una `property` 'online' que es un booleano y tengo que devolver la cantidad total de 'true'.

Lo que podido realizar es lo siguiente pero no funciona.

```js
var nombre: {
  edad: 24,
  online: false
}

var contador = 0;
usuarios.online()

for (let i = 0; i < usuarios.length; i++) {
  if (online === true) {
    contador++
  }
}

return contador;
```

Comment: Tu objeto de ejemplo parece incompleto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu código veo una línea donde pone usuarios.online(), deduzco que se trata de un método de un objeto usuarios.
Y por lo que dices en la descripción de lo que quieres veo que tienes un conjunto de objetos usuario (propiedades edad, online).
Y veo varias soluciones fáciles:

1. Un objeto con muchos objetos dentro y un método online()
2. Un array de objetos usuarios(edad,online) con un método añadido online()
3. Un array de objetos usuario y una función online()

Los tres scripts son muy parecidos, pero te los pongo. Terminan con un sonsole.log para ver el resultado en la consola del panel de desarrollador.

Este es el script para un objeto usuarios que contiene como propiedades objetos usuario.

```js
var usuarios ={
nombre1: {
  edad: 24,
  online: false
},
nombre2: {
  edad: 26,
  online: true
},
nombre3: {
  edad: 20,
  online: true
},
online: function(){
var contador = 0;
for(prop in usuarios)
{
 //solo considera los objetos no el método
     if(prop!='online' && usuarios[prop].online) {contador++};
}
return contador}
}
console.log(usuarios.online())
```

Este otro caso se trata de un array de usuarios al que se le agrega el método online. En el fondo es la misma solución, pero aquí usas el objeto predefinido array en lugar de definir tu propio objeto.

```js
var usuarios =[
{
  edad: 24,
  online: false
},
{
  edad: 28,
  online: true
},
{
  edad: 20,
  online: true
  }
];

usuarios.online = function(){
var contador = 0;
for(i= 0; i < usuarios.length; i++)
{
     if(usuarios[i].online) {contador++};
}
return contador
}
console.log(usuarios.online());
```

Por último con una función (no un método) que recibe como argumento un array de usuarios

```js
var usuarios =[
{
  edad: 24,
  online: false
},
{
  edad: 24,
  online: true
},
{
  edad: 24,
  online: false
  }
];
function online(lista){
var contador= 0; 
for(i=0; i< lista.length;i++){
  if (lista[i].online) contador++
  }
 return contador; 
}
console.log(online(usuarios))
```

Creo que alguna de las versiones te podrá servir. En todas puedes añadir o eliminar usuarios tanto del objeto como del array